# How to fast search in mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb

Currently I use this code to search for the first possible 'slug' based on a string. It is recursive so, it's stops when he found a possible slug.

```
function determineProductSlug(name, count, callback){
    var nameSlug = name;
    if(count > 0){
        nameSlug = name + '-' + count;
    }

    Product.find({'en.nameSlug': nameSlug}).sort({_id: -1}).exec(function(err, product){
        if(err){
            return callback(err);
        }
        if(product.length == 0){
            return callback(null, nameSlug);
        }else{
            count = count+1;
            return determineProductSlug(name, count, callback);
        }
    })
}
```

But, it is getting very slow. We have now arround 10.000 documents in the collection, but that will be many more.

How can I speed this this function/query to operate faster? I have tried it wit the `sort({id: -1})` but that doesn't seems to help.

Comment: Just use `.count()`. It actually does not retrieve any documents at all, and merely returns the cursor count, which is actually from analyzing the query rather than executing and fetching.

Comment: How do your documents look like ? Are they pretty large ?
Do you have the admin access to the database and can you create indexes?

Comment: @A.P. please post that as an answer because it helped me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the rights to do it, one way to improve performances is to create an index on en.nameSlug. Indexes are binary trees kept in memory, that would be the fastest way to find. Indexes can slow down write performances though but you would know if the most important is read or write.